# query is not running in php

Tags: php, mysql, web, wamp

Hi there i am trying to create a screen in php.
in which i select scenario and the screen displayed accordingly.
but i am stuck in a simple problem that my simple select query is not working
which is

```
$deptQuery = "Select * from mcb_department";
echo mysql_real_escape_string($deptQuery);
mysql_query($deptQuery) or die("adfasdf");
```

in same code if change the table name it just work fine, also this table is created in the db as well with the same name i have shared.
here is my complete code.

```
<?php       
    include "include/conn.php";
    include "include/session.php";

    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_user']) && $_SESSION['logged_user'] != '99999'){
        header('location: login.php');
    }

    $query = mysql_query("select curdate() as todayDate");  
    $show = mysql_fetch_array($query);  
    if(isset($show)){                                 
        $todayDate=  $show['todayDate'];
    }

    $group[] = array();
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta Content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" http-Equiv="Cache-Control" />
<meta Content="no-cache" http-Equiv="Pragma" />
<meta Content="0" http-Equiv="Expires" />

    <link href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/popupstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <link href="styles/ts.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/calendar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />         
      <style>
table {
    font-family: arial;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 11px;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body >

</body>

    <select id='select_opt'>
        <option> Select Assigment </option>
        <option value="1"> assign quiz to all Employees </option>
        <option value="2"> assign quiz to Sapcific Group </option>
        <option value="3"> assign quiz to Sapcific Department </option>
        <option value="4"> assign quiz to Sapcific Employee </option>
    </select>

    <!-- all Users -->

    <div id='allUsers' style='margin-left:20px; margin-top: 20px;  width: 50%; height:100px; display: none;' >
        <form action="" mathod="post">
        <select>
            <option value=""> select Quiz</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit"  >
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- group -->

    <div id='group' style='margin-left:20px; margin-top: 20px;  width: 50%; height:100px; display: none;' >

        <form action='group_assigment.php' mathod="post">
        <table>
        <tr>
          <th>All <input type="checkbox"> </th>
          <th>Group Name</th>
          <th>Group Code</th>
        </tr>
         <?php  
               $group[] = array();
               $groupQuery = "Select * from mcb_groups";
               $query = mysql_query($groupQuery);
            ?>
        <tr>
            <?php  if($query){
                   while($group = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                ?>
         <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $group['group_name']; ?>"></td>
          <td><?php echo $group['group_name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $group['group_code']; ?></td>
        </tr>
            <?php }

                   }  else{ echo "";} ?>
        </table>

            </form>

    </div>

    <!-- 
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    department 
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    -->
 <div id='Department' style='margin-left:20px; margin-top: 20px;  width: 50%; height:100px; display: none;' >

   <form action='group_assigment.php' mathod="post">

       <table>
           <tr>
             <th>all <input type="checkbox"> </th>
             <th>name</th>
             <th>code</th>
             <th>group</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <?php
                    $deptQuery = "Select * from mcb_department";
                    echo mysql_real_escape_string($deptQuery);
                    mysql_query($deptQuery);
               ?>
               <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
               <td>code</td>
               <td>name</td>
               <td>group</td>
           </tr>

         </table>
        <input type="submit" >
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- 
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
        Employee 
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    -->    

        <div id='employee' style='margin-left:20px; margin-top: 20px;  width: 50%; height:100px; display: none;' >
         <form action="" mathod="post">
            <label>employee id : </label><input type="text" >
            <input type="submit" >
         </form>
    </div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 var elem = document.getElementById("select_opt");
            elem.onchange = function(){

                            console.log("yes i am running");
                            if( document.getElementById("select_opt").value == "1" ){

                                document.getElementById("allUsers").style.display = "Block";
                                document.getElementById("group").style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById("Department").style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById("employee").style.display = "none";

                            }
                            else if( document.getElementById("select_opt").value == "2" ){

                                document.getElementById("group").style.display = "Block";
                                document.getElementById("allUsers").style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById("Department").style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById("employee").style.display = "none";

                            }
                            else if( document.getElementById("select_opt").value == "3" ){

                                document.getElementById("Department").style.display = "block";
                                document.getElementById("group").style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById("allUsers").style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById("employee").style.display = "none";



                            }
                            else if( document.getElementById("select_opt").value == "4" ){

                                document.getElementById("employee").style.display = "block";
                                document.getElementById("Department").style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById("group").style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById("allUsers").style.display = "none";
                            }

                            else{


                            }



            };
 </script> 

</
```

html>

regard,
Shafee jan

Comment: it's because you are using mysql_* functions

Comment: Any error or something? Or just empty page i.e. no results?

Comment: stop using mysql_* functions it is deprecated

Comment: let me check if its work, But my whole project is working with mysql functions as well.

Comment: now it failing my java script

Comment: You run that query and then you do not process the resultset i.e. there is no `while (...) { output something }`

Answer (score 1):

> in same code if change the table name it just work fine

Then I would make sure you're connected to the right database. It's surprisingly common for developers to have multiple versions of their database, either on different MySQL instances or else on the same instance under a different schema name. Then they get mixed up, connecting to one database with MySQL Workbench while their app is connecting to a different database.

I would advise that you temporarily add a query to your page to run `SHOW TABLES` and then dump the result of that query to the log, to confirm that the `mcb_department` table is present in the database that your PHP script is connected to.

```
$deptQuery = "Select * from mcb_department";
echo mysql_real_escape_string($deptQuery);
mysql_query($deptQuery);
```

Where's your error checking? You need to check the return value of `mysql_query()` *every time* you run a query, so if there's a problem, you output the error message to your log. Only this way can you start to solve some of these problems.

```
$result = mysql_query($deptQuery);
if (!$result) {
    trigger_error("Error in file " . __FILE__ . " near line " . __LINE__ 
      . " for query $deptQuery: " . mysql_error());
    die("Database error");
}
```

PS: The advice of some commenters that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated is true, but probably irrelevant to your question. Folks who focus on the API, when you have said the API is working, are just being pedantic.